# Commonly accepted best practice for using newlines

Tags: java, code-organization

As an extremely jr Software Engineer, I'm trying to make sure I develop good habits.  The challenge of using newlines when displaying output seems very simple (I'm sure to those who are seasoned), but how should they generally be used throughout a program that displays output in various places throughout code execution?

Example (assuming the language is java):

```
public class output
{
   public static String usage = "usage: message";

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("Starting program");
      checkData();
      System.out.println("Ending program");
   }

   public static void checkData()
   {
      System.out.println("Data checked");

      # Assuming this method causes an exception
      try
      {
         more code...
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {
         System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
         System.out.pritnln(usage);
      }
}
```

Clearly all of these messages would run together if everything were to be printed.  So as a program grows, and seeing as though errors necessitate the need to output information as well, should newline characters be placed at the beginning, end, or wherever one decides throughout a program?

Comment: You're not writing a book. For every statement, there should be a newline, IMO. For things like showing titles, tabular data, and cool ASCII art, go as the format requires. Also, look into Logging frameworks.

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure where to ask the question.  Despite all the books I've read and classes that I've taken, I've never seen this discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an advanced feature "aspect oriented programming". 
Spring framework has some built in stuff.

Try to search it, learn how to use it an add some anotation to the functions, it will handle the "entering to the function", "exiting the function" with a simple `@MyLogStuff`

Answer (score 1):

Although, I see a lot of code that's written to log every entry and exit point from each and every method called it isn't one of the good programming practices (it's surprising to some).

The only scenario when you would find this information useful is when you're debugging an exception. But the trace of every method invoked before the exception was thrown is already available in the exception's *stack trace* which leaves this kind of logging redundant.

It's only at places where the exception handling is already questionable that it would help. For e.g, the usual approach of log and forget (to some this is what exception handling is) without giving any serious thought to whether the exception should get escalated or even halt execution or not, and the just plain horrible eating exceptions up with *catch (exception e) {// nothing happened}*.